# I don't understand speaker input wattage

Tags: input

My uncle gave me a pair of Technics SB-CS65 but I can't understand the speaker input rating to get an amp.
It says:

IMPEDANCE: 8 ohm
INPUT: 120W, MUSIC; 60W, DIN.

Comment: Hi. As this question is likely to get voted closed fairly soon as it is off-topic, just going to make a suggestion. The best way to elicit a response on this forum is to ask a question. Literally. Don't assume that forum members will derive a question from your statements. Ask what you want to ask so other forum members can answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the speakers will tolerate 120W of average music power, and 60W RMS according to DIN (which requires loading the speaker at fixed frequencies with the given power for 10 minutes at a time or so).  Basically DIN relates to the power a speaker can dissipate continuously as heat (minus the power actually converted to sound energy, but apart from special horn speakers that tends to be a comparatively minor part of the whole).  "DIN" just means "RMS according to well-defined criteria", and the use of interpunction is a bit confusing, with "," acting for joining and ";" acting for separating clauses.

Comment: So I should get a 60W RMS amp or is it better with 120W RMS as it is average music power as you described?